# Serialize a transaction in python

Tags: transaction, python

I want to use the "Submit a transaction" method in [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io) but it needs an already serialized transaction. Does anybody know how to serialize a transaction in python? (I don't wanna use CLI or anything like that)

Comment: Sadly there isn't an easy way of doing this in Python yet, since the [serialization library][1] is written in Rust with WASM wrappers. At the moment your best bet is to use Javascript/TypeScript in Node, or use pure Rust, or if you're feeling adventurous it is possible to execute rust functions from a Python code base. It just requires a bit of work, [see here.][2]


  [1]: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/
  [2]: https://www.vortexa.com/insight/integrating-rust-into-python

Comment: It is also be possible to construct and sign a transaction using `cardano-cli`. Quickly searching for a python wrapper I've found https://github.com/creativequotient/automint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, there is a python implementation available! https://github.com/cffls/pycardano

I haven't used it myself but the Readme claims this library is able to build and sign transactions. It even comes with an example for exactly this purpose: https://github.com/cffls/pycardano#transaction-creation-and-signing

Comment: That was a lifesaver. Thanks, man!

Comment: Can it compile Plutus.  I looked at the docs but I am too new to this whole thing to even be able to tell.  I just want to programmatically generate simple scripts.